# Serial console output but USB keyboard input ignored?

Tags: grub2

my server doesn't have VGA output, so my only luck will be serial console; However, my serial cable is 2-3 crossed and somehow could only output screen but take no input, I am trying to think if it's possible to use serial console for output and USB keyboard for input at the same time, how could I config this?

I am currently using console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 on Grub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of an usb keyboard without screen in parallel to an Serial Console does not work and does not make sense.

You need usb Null Modem serial cable. (DB9 Serial DCE Adapter Cable with FTDI - Null Modem) ask Google ...

I recommend as grub parameter

```
console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprint=serial,ttyS0,115200
```

works since years ....

if you use a standard USBto Serial cable you need a Null Modem Seral Cable, [image: null modem Cable setup]

only 2-3 crossed in not a full null modem cable.

Comment: I have a null modem cable but only 2-3 crossed, do you think this is related with handshake feature?

Comment: @Thomas G. Lau  Crossing only 2-3  is not enough

Comment: I saw your diagram, what's the actual name of this null modem cable? Full handshake?

Comment: see details here: [Wikipedia null modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem)